# How can I perform a linear regression on my group variances in R?

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

Here is my data

[image]

Comparing the mean seems to yield to some interested results. And it indeed does as revealed by the linear model:

```
lm(data=data, y~factor(x)))
```

Now, it also looks like the variances are not equal in all groups. Here is a plot of the variance in `y` for each group in `x`.

[image]

I'd be interested to test different linear regression to see if a quadratic regression is a better model than a linear model (compared by AIC or BIC).

I could estimate the sampling distribution for the variance and get a confidence interval for the variance in each group, so it should be feasible to perform a regression on the variance of my groups. However, I don't know how to perform a  regression on my sample variances in R.

**How can I perform a linear regression on my group variances in R?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use a polynomial to model variances. Among the variance functions offered by package nlme is `varConstPower`. Let's try this:

```
n <- c(1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32)
v <- c(5.85, 6.35, 6.55, 6.85, 7.02, 7.15) 

plot(v ~ n)
```

[image: plot variance vs n]

```
fit_ConstPower <- nls(v ~ n^(2*theta) + c, 
                       start = list(theta = 2, c = 4), 
                       data = data.frame(n, v))
summary(fit_ConstPower)
lines(npred <- seq(1, 32, length.out = 100),
      predict(fit_ConstPower, newdata = data.frame(n = npred)),
      col = "blue")
```

[image: plot with first fit added]

However, that doesn't seem to be a good fit. To me it looks more like there might be saturation:

```
fit_hyper <- nls(v ~ k * n^(theta) + c, 
               start = list(k = -1, theta = -1, c = 7.2), 
               data = data.frame(n, v))
summary(fit_hyper)
lines(npred,
      predict(fit_hyper, newdata = data.frame(n = npred)),
      col = "green")
```

[image: plot with second fit added]

PS: I'm having trouble understanding your question. The literal answer would be so simple (just use `lm`) that I must miss something. Furthermore, you don't tell us whether `x` is a covariate or something else (e.g., sample size?). Thus, I can't even guess if there might be some fundamental relationship behind what you observe.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a package called 'glmnet' in R. This library is used for generalized linear models. Included Multivariated Linear Regression. If you are familiar with lasso or ridge penalization glmnet( ) function performs a regression with a combination of both penalizations. And cv.glmnet( ) function performs a crossvalidated model for choosing the best penalization parameter(s).

So, you can do the following:

```
library('glmnet')
x <- yourdata[sample(1:nrow(mydata),]
cv.model1 <- cv.glmnet(x,y,alpha = your_parameter)
```

Or if you want to get the simplest linear regression model
you can use de lm( ) function which doesnt perform penalization.

```
simple_model <- lm(y~x,data=data.frame(x,y))
```

For more info on both models visit the documentation for the corresponding functions. Hope this helps.